# error e.rest apigility how create db connect services?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

i'm try created db connect services but don't work
i'm have the error e.rest to try create services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvnwn.jpg)

i'm try with this solution but not working have the same error

```
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui": "dev-master"
```

maybe some one have the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute in the directory where you apigility files are located

```
php composer.phar install
```

and to be sure

```
php composer.phar update
```

otherwise the changes won't take action